# Why does convergence in law not worry about points of discontinuity?

Tags: probability-theory

Wikipedia states that the definition of [convergence in law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution) only requires that the cumulative distribution functions of the sequence of variables converges pointwise to the CDF of the limit variable *at points where the CDF of the limit variable is continuous*.

If I were to define convergence in law, I think I would define it as:

> $X_n$ converges to $X$ in law if for every event (measurable set of the image space) $E$, $\text P(X_n\in E)\to\text P(X\in E)$

The definition on Wikipedia seems to *almost* verify the above, but if $x$ is any point of discontuinity, we might not have $\text P(X_n<x)\to\text P(X<x)$. Why not just require convergence everywhere?

Comment: Wikipedia itself gives an answer to your question right after the definition.

Comment: @sanjab Perhaps I should have mentioned that I don't really understand the point of the example. Given that $F_n(0)=0$ for all $0$ but $F(0)=1$, I would find it more natural to just conclude that there isn't convergence in law. I don't see how the example is supposed to motivate changing the definition.

Answer (score 3):

> $X_n$ converges to $X$ in law if for every event (measurable set of the image space) $E$, $\text P(X_n\in E)\to\text P(X\in E)$

is too strong a definition for weak convergence/convergence in distribution.

For instance, if $X_n$ is such that $P(X_n=1/n)=1$, and $X$ is such that $P(X=0)=1$, then it is intuitively clear that $X_n \rightarrow X$ (and it does converge according to the accepted characterization of convergence: $Ef(X_n) \rightarrow Ef(X)$ for all bounded, continuous functions f), but your definition above would lead to a wrong conclusion - take E to be the set $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: I guess the trouble is that this is basically a subjective question... to me it's not intuitively clear that $X_n\to X$, since as you say, their laws disagree for certain events.

Comment: I think it all boils down to which definition leads to a useful theory. I'm by no means an expert. But since this is classical stuff, I'm guessing probabilists think that the relaxed definition is more rich.